# Can the letter $\epsilon$ be defined as a parameter instead of the conventional meaning?

Tags: proof-writing, notation

If in some sections of my proof, $\epsilon$ represents the common meaning of the small variable approaching zero, while in another section of the proof, $\epsilon $  is defined as a parameter, would it be considered "unconventional notation" or "bad grammar"?

Comment: When speaking about children, Erdös used to name them $\epsilon$'s !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Like Erdos was writing a story or was he creating a fun math problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed an unconventional notation, but not bad grammar at all. On the other hand, it is not at all a good option to use, within a single proof, the same symbol for two different objects.

Comment: Shoot, I worked pretty meticulously to make sure that in no symbol in my 130 page thesis was used to mean more than one thing.  Given that I talk about primes, poles, probabilities, and a few other p-things, I started getting pretty desperate towards the end.  I will admit, however, that $\mu$ got used to denote a few distinct measures.  One hopes that the local scope of each usage was clear.